# Bucle Determinado For

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, consola

tengo un problema en los bucles determinados for. Resulta que escribo mi código y aparece en consola lo siguiente:

> exercise.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
> at exercise.js:2
> (anonymous) @ exercise.js:2

Y este es mi còdigo en mi hoja de javascript puro:

```
let numbers=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
for (let i=0;i<numbers.length;i++);{
    console.log(numbers[i]);
}
```

No entiendo porque la consola me aparece que la variable i no esta definida si en el código javascript claramente aparece dentro del paréntesis de for, de acuerdo a lo que entiendo con
for la variable i se escribe junto a for y dentro del parentesis, y no afuera como asi lo escribo con la variable numbers para el array. La verdad no entiendo mi error

Comment: tenéis un ";" de más... al cerrar el paréntesis del for no va el ";"

Comment: Quita el * ; * (Punto y coma) luego de los parentesi del for, antes de abrir las llaves.. te comento que nunca pense ver esto sin que dara algun tipo de error.

Comment: comprendo gracias!

Answer (score 1):

ya lo solucione, la razón era que como i=0; y el array tenia empezando con un 0 daba error, porque como bien debes saber i dara las vueltas hasta llenar todos los saltos del array que son 7 a pesar de que sean solo 6 elementos es lo que tiene la propiedad length, por lo tanto lo que hacia era que como i<0 e i=0 entonces 0 no puede ser menor que 0 y ahi estaba el error lo que hice fue quitar el 0 del array y empezar desde 1 y me fue de maravilla, igual gracias por responder tan prontamente saludos!